# How to separate logs for multiple bots

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, influxdb

I want to use InfluxDB to store logs and then view them in Grafana. What the best way to separate logs from different bots?

I think about create new db for each bot or just put a tag with bot id to metrics, what's better?

Comment: Distinguish logs between different bots or different conversations within the same bot?

Comment: Yeah, different bots

Answer (score 0):

Configure the application logging format including a prefix (bot Id)

```
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - (BOT1) %(message)s',
                        level=DefaultConfig.LOG_LEVEL)
```

Log entries generated by each bot will be different and can be aggregate/queried in the logging aggregation tools (like Grafana)

```
2021-03-19 11:32:20,952 - INFO - (BOT1) Start polling mode
```